# Does snappy support streaming data

Tags: c++, streaming, snappy

I was trying to use the c++ client for snappy with libevent, and I was wondering whether it supports streaming data.  For example is it possible for me to read from a socket and tell if the entire compressed data has been read?

Would I have to resort to prepending the compressed data with a content length integer?